# Coffeescript with google maps variable scope

Tags: javascript, google-maps, coffeescript

I am trying to make google maps play nice with coffeescript. The problem I have is that coffeescript wraps javascript in `(function() {` which mean variables dont make the global scope.

Is there a way to make coffeescript force variables into the global scope?

Below is an example of the simple code I have currently.

```
initialize = ->
  options = 
      lat:-34.456
      lng:23.456
      zoom: 10
  map = new google.maps.Map document.getElementById('map-canvas'), options
  return

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize)
```

Comment: Why do you need them to be globals? In general, globals are things to *avoid*.

Comment: How can I make use of google maps with coffeescript without using globals? Sorry new to this.

Comment: I edited your initialize function to have a body. I think you intended that, but if not, you can edit it back.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you want to *avoid* globals.

If you absolutely need to create a global, though, you can do it by assigning to a property on `window`:

```
window.foo = "bar";
```

That creates a global called `foo` (which can be used without the `window.`), because all global variables are really properties of the global object, and on browsers the global object is the Window object, which is accessible through the `window` global.

Comment: How can i use google maps within coffeescript as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

two options:

you can either attach to the window, or the global namespaces

```
 window.initialize = ->
```

or in the browser, the reference to `this` will be window, so

```
@initialize = ->
```

or create your own namespace and attach there:

```
myApp ?= {}
myApp.intialize = ->
```

then some other place (like maybe in your jQuery ready handler as shown here):

```
$->
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', myApp.initialize)
```